# Determining the orbit decomposition of a certain group action on $R^2$

Tags: group-theory, linear-transformations, group-actions

I have the group
$$G = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
 : a,b \in R, a \neq 0\right\}$$
and the map $\wedge: G \times R^2 \to R^2$ defined by $$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \wedge(x,y) = (ax+by, y).$$

I have already shown that $\wedge$ defines a group action on the plane. All I have left to do is determine and describe its orbits:

When $y = 0$ we have 
$$Orb(x,0) = \{(ax,0): a \in R,a \neq 0 \} .$$
This is just the $x$ axis excluding the origin.

When $x = 0$ we have 
$$Orb(0,y) = \{(by,y): b \in R \}$$
If I set $x = by \implies y = x/b$ so this is the set of lines through the origin with gradient $1/b$. Not including the origin itself.

Finally with both $x$ and $y$ not equal to $0$,
$$Orb(x,y) = \{(ax+by,y): a,b \in R, a \neq 0 \}.$$
Again setting $x = ax+by$ we have $y = \frac{x(1-a)}{b}$. This is the set of lines through by not including the origin with gradient  $\frac{(1-a)}{b}$.

Finally with both $x,y$ equal to $0$, we have the origin.

I don't feel as though this is correct as the orbits of a group action partition the plane into distinct sets. Could someone give me a little help here please?

Comment: Which is the given action of the group on the plane? The one given by left matrix multiplication?

Comment: Yes, i should have included that in my post. I will edit it now.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE I do not exactly understand your confusion but x-axis minus the origin is one orbit, the origin is another orbit and so on

Comment: I would like to confirm that i have given a geometric description of all the orbits of the action, please.

Comment: What makes you think you haven't partitioned $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: Orb(0,y) and Orb(x,y) are not distinct, i don't think. Oh wait, a is non zero! Right thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decomposition given in the question is not the orbit decomposition.

**Hint** Note that the given action,
$$\pmatrix{a & b \\ 0 & 1} \wedge (x, y) := (ax + by, y)$$
(which is just the restriction of the standard action of $GL(2, \Bbb R)$ on $\Bbb R^2$, namely the one given by left matrix multiplication, to our group $G$), fixes the second component of every element in $\Bbb R^2$. So, whatever the orbit decomposition is, each orbit is a subset of a horiztonal line $\{y = y_0\}$ for some $y_0$, and henceforth we need only understand the behavior of the first component.